# Pretrained ResNet-50 on ImageNet as CAE encoder performs very poor

Tags: pytorch, autoencoder, transfer-learning

I am experementing with different Convolutional Autoencoder Arcitectures now and I have decided to try pretrained ResnNet50 network as encoder in my model. I tried to options: use encoder without changing weights and use encoder using pretrained weights as initial. I had better results of reconstructing training weights of ResNet, but it still cannot outperform my basic CAE with 3 conv layer in encoder and 3 upsample + conv2d layers in decoder. Can you help me with the explanation of such effect? I am training my network on different domains of OfficeHome dataset. Here is my arcitecture:

```
class ConvBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(ConvBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1, stride=1)
        self.relu = nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True)
        self.norm = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.norm(x)
        return x

class ResnetConvAutoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ResnetConvAutoencoder, self).__init__()
        resnet = models.resnet50(pretrained = True, progress = True)
        
#         for param in resnet.parameters():
#             param.requires_grad = False
        
        self.encoder = torch.nn.Sequential(*(list(resnet.children())[:-2])) #output is 2048 x 8 x 8

        del resnet

        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
           nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
           ConvBlock(2048, 512),
           
           nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
           ConvBlock(512, 256),
            
           nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
           ConvBlock(256, 128),
            
           nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
           ConvBlock(128, 16),
           
           nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
           ConvBlock(16, 3),
          
           nn.Sigmoid()
        ) # output is 3 x 256 x 256 (as input)
        
        self.encoder.cuda(2) # trainig on several GPUs
        self.decoder.cuda(1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.cuda(2)
        x = self.encoder(x).cuda(1)
        x = self.decoder(x).cuda(1)
        return x
```

And some images examples of my simple CAE and CAE with ResNet encoder

[image: ResNet-50 encoder results]

[image: My simple CAE with low amount of layers]

Loss on train and test in CAE with ResNet-50 is about 0.03 and do not go lower. Loss in my CAE is lower than 0.015 (MSE).